# How do you plot a contour plot of energy gain in for changing epsilon on python?

Tags: python, 2d, contour

I've been trying to make a contour plot for varying epsilon_1 and epsilon_2 having energy gain as the contour part but I'm not sure how to code it as I keep getting errors when I try anything with

```
epsilon_1= np.linspace(1,25,1000)
epsilon_2= np.linspace(1,25,1000)
E=1/2*((epsilon_1)/(epsilon_2)+1)
```

can anyone tell me how to code this properly to get a contour plot of this please?

I tried plt.contour and plt.tricontourf but they didnt work because my E isnt 2D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use numpy.meshgrid to turn them into 2d.

You can use contourf instead of contour if you want filled, rather than line, contours.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

epsilon_1= np.linspace(1,25,1000)
epsilon_2= np.linspace(1,25,1000)

eps1, eps2 = np.meshgrid( epsilon_1, epsilon_2 )
E=0.5 * ( eps1 / eps2 + 1 )

plt.contour( eps1, eps2, E, 100 )
plt.show()
```

[image]